# Implementing a DSL on .NET

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, expression-trees, dsl

I'm implementing a small DSL on top of .NET (4.0) and I'm currently using Expression Trees to turn the DSL into chunks of executable code.

The DSL is predefined as we're implementing support for a legacy file format.

Are Expression Trees the most appropriate tool for this job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expression Trees are useless if you want to generate new types. And for most of the typical DSLs you have to build types. So, a good old `System.Reflection.Emit` is likely to be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @SK-logic. Could you expand a little, please. Why are Expression Trees "useless unless you want to generate new types", and how would `Reflection.Emit` serve me better?

Comment: @GregB, I meant the opposite - expression trees cannot be used for generating new types. You can only compile them into delegates. Imagine, say, a DSL for some kind of ORM, which would map a database to a hierarchy of objects. It must emit types for that objects, and you can only do it with Reflection.Emit.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) and more specific at [Rhino.DSL](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-dsl/), which is built on it. To get an impression of what Boo brings on the table, [Ayende's posts](http://ayende.com/blog/tags/boo) are a great starter.

Boo is described by its inceptors as:

> a new object oriented statically typed programming language for the Common Language Infrastructure with a python inspired syntax and a special focus on language and compiler extensibility.

So basically, it's an alternative to C#: also compiled, but much more flexible, in such a way that you can dynamically setup new language constructs. Expression trees are only a fraction of what's involved.

By putting Boo somewhere in your pipeline, as Rhino.DSL does, you unleash a lot of versatility that's not even necessary bloated or a performance hog (it's still compiled bytecode that runs).

If you take a look at [the unit tests on Rhino.DSL](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-dsl/blob/master/Rhino.DSL.Tests/OrderDSL/OrderBusinessRules.boo), you'll get a quick impression of what's possible.

One note though: all mentioned repositories are pretty inactive at the moment (no activity within the last year), but IMHO that does not devalue their practical use.

Hope this might help you.